# PHP Minify Crashing in Sub-Directory - WAMP

Tags: php, apache, wamp, minify

I followed the PHP Minify instructions listed on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/AlternateFileLayouts) to use a sub-directory, but it just returns a 400 bad request error at my test URL. Any ideas or leads on how to fix this?

**Steps I followed**

1. Put min folder relative to my "demo-site's" root
2. Added code snippet below as directed on the [instructions page](http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/AlternateFileLayouts).
3. Ran the URL test, returns a 400 bad request error.

**More Info**

Server: Wamp PHP v5.3

Location on server: var/www/demo-site

URL giving a 400 error: [http://localhost/demo-site/min/f=min/quick-test.js](http://example.com)

Code placed in config.php

```
// Set the document root to be the path of the "site root"
$min_documentRoot = substr(__FILE__, 0, -15);

// Set $sitePrefix to the path of the site from the webserver's real docroot
list($sitePrefix) = explode('/min/index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 2);

// Prepend $sitePrefix to the rewritten URIs in CSS files
$min_symlinks['//' . ltrim($sitePrefix, '/')] = $min_documentRoot;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the version of Minify I'm using you have to find the following lines (shown in code sample below) with a search and replace them in config.php. Simply copying and pasting this code into config.php blows everything up. Which is unexpected since the documentation at the time of writing this pretty much says copy and paste the code snippet...

```
// Search for...
$min_documentRoot = '';
// Replace with...
$min_documentRoot = pathinfo(pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_DIRNAME), PATHINFO_DIRNAME);

// Search for...
$min_symlinks = array();
// Replace with...
list($sitePrefix) = explode('/min/index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 2); 
$min_symlinks['//' . ltrim($sitePrefix, '/')] = $min_documentRoot;
```